# Can you put multiple conditions in a if statement?

Tags: python

For example:

The if statement would take input from the user and would run the correct function for it.

```
if x == 1 or 2 or 3:
do this or that
```

Comment: Use an elif (else if) after. This or that are separate functions, right?

Comment: your code has a bug. you should fix it so the if stmt does what you would expect.

Comment: What do you mean by "the if statement would take input from the user"?

Answer (score 4):

Your current statement will always be true. It checks if `x == 1` which may be true or false, then it checks the value `2` which is true, because all nonzero integers are "truthy". (And similarly for `3`)

The correct way to check a single variable against multiple values is to use:

```
if x == 1 or x == 2 or x == 3:
```

Or, you could check if x is in a collection of values. This is usually the preferred way if there are lots of possible values to check.

```
if x in {1, 2, 3}:
```

This uses a set literal, but you could use any collection type such as a list or a tuple instead.

If you need to take a different action depending on the value of x, you can use if, elif, else

```
if x == 1:
    # do something
elif x == 2:
    # do something different
else:
    # x did not match any of your values so raise an error or something
```

Comment: +on for explaining the “bug” in code, which other answer fail to do unfortunately. good work

Answer (score 1):

yes, you would want to do

```
if x == 1 or x == 2 or x == 3:
  ...
```

or you could do

```
if x in [1 ,2]:
   ...
```

in python